# Samba over http/https?

Tags: networking, samba

This is a very niche problem and I do not know how to tackle this. I have one network with a firewall stopping the normal samba ports of 445 and 139 but letting normal website ports through, I can not change this firewall. I have a server on a different network running a samba server with those ports port forwarded. The server is properly configured and can be accessed else where. When connecting from the firewalled network to the samba server the connection is blocked. Is there any way of changing the samba ports (but still letting a windows computer connect, apparently windows computers can not connect to non-standard ports for samba), or somehow running it separately through a http/https website, or a https proxy somehow? Any ideas?

I've tried connecting to the samba server via a browser. And so far have been connecting to a hotspot to connect to the samba server which is inconvenient. I've done some research on samba ports, but have quickly realized that the Windows only accepts the true samba ports.

And after doing a bit more research i found that the port 22 for ssh is also blocked on the network

I hope this makes sense.

Thankyou in advance